# How do I run a similar script on multiple tabs in a sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that sends an email with data from the new row after a new form submission.  I want to run the script on multiple sheets. To be more specific, I use a query function to sort data after the form submission and I want each tab to send an email if that sheet has a row added.

I don't know where to start

Answer (score 0):

This function is called for each form submission

```
function runAFunctionOnMultipleSheets(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  ["Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3"].forEach((n,i) => {
    let sh = ss.getSheetByName(n);//this section runs for each sheet
    //Run your code in here for each sheet e contains data from trigger event object
  })
}
```

Run this function to create form Submit trigger

```
function createFormSubmit() {
  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "runAFunctionOnMultipleSheets").forEach(t => ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(t));
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("runAFunctionOnMultipleSheets").forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onEdit().create();
}
```